# electric-pair-mode and Python triple quotes

Tags: python, emacs

Is there a way to enable auto-pairing Python triple quotes in electric-pair-mode?

This can be configured in autopair-mode using `autopair-python-triple-quote-action`. Is there a similar way to enable this in electric-pair-mode?

Comment: You might also look at [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following:

```el
(defun python-electric-pair-string-delimiter ()
  (when (and electric-pair-mode
             (memq last-command-event '(?\" ?\'))
             (let ((count 0))
               (while (eq (char-before (- (point) count)) last-command-event)
                 (setq count (1+ count)))
               (= count 3)))
    (save-excursion (insert (make-string 3 last-command-event)))))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
                      #'python-electric-pair-string-delimiter 'append t)))
```

It will be included in the next release of Emacs.