# Custom Pairs in Emacs electric-pair-mode

Tags: emacs, markdown

When writing markdown in emacs markdown-mode, I would like electric-pair-mode to automatically close
`**bold**` and `*italic*` pair syntax, i.e. when entering one * a second *  should appear automatically beyond the cursor or when entering ** another ** should automatically appear beyond the cursor.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Why don't you use, `C-c C-s b` for bold and `C-c C-s I` for italics?

Comment: 1/2 key presses instead of 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding this to your `.emacs` should do what you want for one `*`

```
(electric-pair-mode 1)
(defvar markdown-electric-pairs '((?* . ?*)) "Electric pairs for markdown-mode.")
(defun markdown-add-electric-pairs ()
  (setq-local electric-pair-pairs (append electric-pair-pairs markdown-electric-pairs))
  (setq-local electric-pair-text-pairs electric-pair-pairs))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'markdown-add-electric-pairs)
```

Comment: OK - this works now for italic. Thanks!

 I will try now to adopt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676181/electric-pair-mode-and-python-triple-quotes for `**bold**` electric pairs.